# Конвертирую javascript в php. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в двух строчках javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, конвертация

Большая часть кода мне понятна и я могу перевести большую часть кода в php, но не смог разобраться в двух строках, а именно:

```
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;
 if (typeof phantom !== 'undefined') return 'phantom' if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) return 'node' if (n==0) return 0;
```

Помогите пожалйста разобраться в этих строчках, на русском языке, а в php я с русского сам переведу :)

А это весь сурс кода для общей картины:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function leastFactor(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;
 if (typeof phantom !== 'undefined') return 'phantom' if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) return 'node' if (n==0) return 0;
 if (n%1 || n*n<2) return 1;
 if (n%2==0) return 2;
 if (n%3==0) return 3;
 if (n%5==0) return 5;
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
  if (n%i==0)      return i;
  if (n%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
  if (n%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
  if (n%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
  if (n%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
  if (n%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
  if (n%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
  if (n%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
 }
 return n;
}
function go() {
 var p=2176360431396; var s=661957388; var n;
if ((s >> 4) & 1)   p+= 211939363*7;
else /*
p+= */p-=156854666*/* 120886108*
*/5; if ((s >> 1) & 1)p+=/* 120886108*
*/702658818*/*
*13;
*/2;/* 120886108*
*/else p-=/*
*13;
*/767591891*2;  if ((s >> 14) & 1)/*
p+= */p+=103895464* 17;/*
else p-=
*/else p-=/*
p+= */100858337*15;/* 120886108*
*/if ((s >> 3) & 1) p+=/*
*13;
*/324805*/*
else p-=
*/4;
else    p-=/*
p+= */328239546*/*
else p-=
*/4;/*
else p-=
*/if ((s >> 1) & 1)/*
*13;
*/p+=/*
else p-=
*/650056741*    2;/* 120886108*
*/else /*
*13;
*/p-=   294783819*
2;/*
p+= */ p+=2439047088;
 n=leastFactor(p);
{ document.cookie="RNKEY="+n+"*"+p/n+":"+s+":1250303931:1";
  document.location.reload(true); }
}
//--></script>
```

Comment: ru.SO это не сайт по конвертации кода. Это место, где людям _помогают_ с их конкретными проблемами. Как следствие, вам стоит потратить немного времени и попытаться решить проблему самостоятельно. А если что-то не получится, то вы всегда сможете задать _конкретный_ вопрос о локализованной проблеме.

Comment: В заголовке я задал вопрос касательно возможности, `"Можно ли полноценно перевести данный код в из javascript в php и выполнить его?"` Касательно конвертации - не нашёл сайта, который смог бы ответить на этот вопрос, поэтому задал его тут!

Comment: Отвечаю: можно. А вопрос в текущей постановке не формат для ru.SO. См. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1575/182771

Comment: ок, я сейчас перефразирю вопрос, меня интересуют конкретные строчки, с которыми я не смог разобраться...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: перефразировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `isNaN()` проверяет содержит ли переменная значения NaN, undefiend и т.п. в этом случае возвращается true. То есть содержит ли переменная число в любом виде, будь то true, null, 0, "1" и т.д. в данном случае false.

Функция `isFinite()` проверяет содержит ли переменная число в конечном\конкретном цифровом виде например: 4, 2e34 и т.д. Если переменная содержит конкретные значения то вернётся true, иначе если переменная содержит значения типа Infinity, NaN вернётся false.

Таким образом в первой строке проверяем переменную содержит ли она числовое значение.

Функция `typeof` возвращает тип переменной, т.е. если она содержит значения true\false вернётся "boolean", если же переменная undefined вернётся "undefined".

То есть во второй строке идёт проверка инициализированы ли переменные, если да, идёт возврат строки со значением типа.